# Puppet not passing parameter to custom module

Tags: puppet, automation, puppet-agent

So I have a custom module that just sets up a simple nginx server, to learn how to properly make puppet modules.

But it seems that my values when I declare the class aren't getting passed in.  It just uses the default values instead.

Below is my bits of class code that matter, and the `base.pp` I'm using in my control repo.

**Base class** `init.pp`:

```
class ufprovisioning (

    $webserver_manage   = $ufprovisioning::params::webserver_manage,
    $site_name          = $ufprovisioning::params::site_name,


) inherits ufprovisioning::params {

    contain ufprovisioning::install
    contain ufprovisioning::config
    contain ufprovisioning::service

    Class['::ufprovisioning::install'] -> Class['::ufprovisioning::config'] ~> Class['::ufprovisioning::service']
    Class['::ufprovisioning::install'] ~> Class['::ufprovisioning::service']
}
```

**Parameter Class** `params.pp`:

```
class ufprovisioning::params {

    $site_name = "webserver.test"
    $webserver_manage = true

}
```

**Config Class** `config.pp`:

```
class ufprovisioning::config {

    assert_private()

    $webserver_manage   = $::ufprovisioning::params::webserver_manage
    $site_name          = $::ufprovisioning::params::site_name


    nginx::resource::server { 'cclloyd.com':
        ensure          =>  present,
        server_name     =>  [$site_name],
        www_root        =>  "/var/www/${site_name}",
        listen_port     =>  80,
        ssl             =>  false,
    }
}
```

**Control class** `base.pp`:

```
class profile::base {
    class { '::ntp': }
    class { 'ufprovisioning':
        site_name => "examplesite.test",
        webserver_manage => true,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ufprovisioning::config` class is setting variable values directly from `ufprovisioning::params`, but you are setting values with the `ufprovisioning` top-scope class when you declare it in `profile::base`.

Let me phrase it a slightly different way in case that doesn't make sense. 
You are setting parameter values for init.pp via base.pp which gets default values from params.pp. However, that logic is broken because config.pp gets values *directly* from params.pp. To solve this, config.pp should inherit values from init.pp.

You could fix it by moving the variables into `ufprovisioning::config` class parameters which inherit from the top-scope class like this;

```
class ufprovisioning::config (
    $webserver_manage   = $::ufprovisioning::webserver_manage
    $site_name          = $::ufprovisioning::site_name
) inherits ufprovisioning {

    assert_private()

    nginx::resource::server { 'cclloyd.com':
        ensure          =>  present,
        server_name     =>  [$site_name],
        www_root        =>  "/var/www/${site_name}",
        listen_port     =>  80,
        ssl             =>  false,
    }
}
```

But, be warned, even this is no longer the suggested pattern used with more recent Puppet versions and Hiera 5.